# Switching between input sources (keyboard layouts) only works sporadically (after upgrade to ubuntu 22 LTS)

Tags: upgrade, keyboard

I am located in Swityerland.
My physical keyboard layout is swiss german.

Language for text in windows:
English (United States)

Formats:
Switzerland

I need to use more than one language though.
So I have these keyboards installed:

- English (United States)
- German (Switzerland)
- Russian

Input Source Switching is set to
use the same source for all windows.

Switch to next input source is set to
CTRL-SPACE

Switch to previous input source is set to
SHIFT-CTRL-SPACE

After upgrading from ubuntu 20 LTS to 'Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS', I have trouble selecting the input source (ie the keyboard layout). Sometimes it works, sometimes not at all.

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-52-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-032) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

I think the following confirms I am using gnome:

```
$ ps auwxf | grep gnome | grep --invert-match 'grep'
claus       2847  0.0  0.1 593824 18396 ?        Ssl  20:21   0:00      \_ /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --builtin --session=budgie-desktop
claus       3280  0.0  0.1 376664 25112 ?        Sl   20:21   0:00          \_ gnome-screensaver
claus       3076  0.0  0.0 162748  8112 ?        Sl   20:21   0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
claus       2841  0.0  0.0 241256  7564 ?        Sl   20:21   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

Comment: Normally I would also expect the top menu bar will show a small icon (indicator) with the current layout, and allow you to change layouts by clicking on it and selecting another one. But it is no longer there after the upgrade.

Comment: I presume you're using Gnome. So, unless you did some custom setup through `setxkbmap` *(which theoretically might conflict with e.g. Mutter tracking of layouts)* or something similar through `gsettings` *(I recall there's a way to pass XKB options, and I think if you pass language-related ones there, it may confuse Mutter)*, the only other reason I can think of is a bug.

Comment: I noticed, you mention in comment there's no keyboard-layout related icon. So, unless prev. comment about some special custom configuration applies, try also removing layouts in gnome-settings completely and then adding them back. Does it make the icon appear?

Comment: You list your Ubuntu as version 22. this must mean your are using Ubuntu Core 22 as this is the only version of Ubuntu that uses a single digit version number. If this is not the case please edit and correct the info. A actual version number is important as there are currently 3 different versions of Ubuntu that are being called 22 by people trying to use short forms. Ubuntu 22.10, Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu core 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

I managed to display the currently selected input method again:
Budgie Desktop Settings | Top Panel | add applet 'Keyboard Layout'.

The 'Keyboard Layout' applet appeared, and correctly displayed the three installed keyboards. But selecting a keyboard using it had no effect.

Then in
**Budgie Control Center | Keyboard | Keyboard Shortcuts | View And Customize Shortcuts | Typing**

I removed the overrides for selecting the input source I had used previously (before upgrading to 22). This resulted in

Switch to next input source is set to
Alt Shift L

Switch to previous input source is set to
Shift Super Space

From then on, it worked. I can now select the keyboard using the desktop applet, or I can use the key combinations for switching to next or previous input source.

Comment: thanks for fixing up the syntax.